# iOS Keyboard extension: able to display key tap beyond keyboard field?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I am working on a iOS Keyboard extension app, where similar to the aesthetic of the default keyboard, a zoom-in view of the key appears to confirm to the user which key they have just tapped on.

This works well for lower row keys such as "Z":

[image]

However, when it comes to top row keys, I find that I am unable to go beyond the **view space of the keyboard**, so that taps look like the following:

[image]

I was wondering if anyone has found a workaround to this, so that the keys could actually display over the app in which the keyboard extension is active? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't draw outside the keyboard window.

If you look at the view hierarchy you can see that the custom keyboard is in a separate UIWindow and it's bounds prevent you from drawing above the top of the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks Joe, looks like I need to find a workaround to this then.

Comment: One workaround is to have extra space above the top row of your keyboard, it will be within your keyboard's window.  Then your keys can expand into that area.  You can use the extra space for word predictions or something else.